# Foreign key return object instead of integer

Tags: django-models

in "models.py"

```
class Run(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(choices=((int(x), x) for x in range(1, 50)))
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=((str(x), x) for x in ['bit', 'casing']))
    run_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    well = models.ForeignKey(Well, related_name='run', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='run_created_by', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Run Information"
        verbose_name_plural = "Run Information"

    def __int__(self):
        return self.number

class BitRun(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=((int(x), x) for x in range(1, 50)))
    od = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    inner_diameter = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    tfa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    bottom_depth = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    top_depth = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, related_name='bit_number', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    well = models.ForeignKey(Well, related_name='well_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Bit Record"
        verbose_name_plural = "Bit Records"
```

in "admin.py"

```
class BitRunAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('number',)
    list_display = ('well', 'run',  'od', 'tfa')
    list_filter = ['well']
    search_fields = ['well']
```

[I see run object(1) instead of the actual fields value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuAZQ.png)

Can someone please point what i am doing wrong in the code?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `__str__` representation for each model.

```
def __str__(self):
    rerurn f"{self.field_name}"
```

`field_name` must be the name of field you want to see.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it made sense. What is the reason for not being able to use __int__ instead of converting it to str? I didn't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: I have not used __int__ so far anywhere in my Django models. It is used for type conversion I suppose, `__str__()` is basically a string representation of the object.